# How can I use the chr(int(" ",2)) function in python to convert the 8 bits binary values stored in a string to get their respective characters

Tags: python, binary

```
string="01101000011001010110110001101100011011110010000001110111011011110111001001101100011001000010000000100001"
listnew=[]
start=0
end=8
for i in range(0,len(string)):
               print(string[start:end:1],end=' ')
               listnew.append(string[start:end:1])
               y = (string[start:end:1])
               x= chr(int(y,2))
               start=start+8
               end=end+8
               print(x)
```

here x= chr(int(y,2)) which should be x=char(int("10101010",2)) some binary value instead of varable y inside " ", but I am getting the following error

```
x= chr(int(y,2))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: ''
```

My question is can someone tell me how can I modify this to get desired results, I am basically trying the get the characters by reading 8 bits binary substrings from the given string then see the ASCII values  and will finally save those characters in a string again.

Comment: How can I use the chr(int(“ ”,2)) function in python to convert the 8 bits binary values stored in a string to get their respective characters, but the problem here is that I have 8 bits binary values stored in a variable but the function chr(int(" "),2) uses explicit values of binary numbers inside

Answer (score 0):

The smallest change to your code, to fix the problem you're having, is to add a non-emptiness check for `y` before doing `x = chr(int(y,2))`:

```py
string="01101000011001010110110001101100011011110010000001110111011011110111001001101100011001000010000000100001"
listnew=[]
start=0
end=8
for i in range(0,len(string)):
    print(string[start:end:1],end=' ')
    listnew.append(string[start:end:1])
    y = (string[start:end:1])
    if not y:
        break
    x = chr(int(y,2))
    start=start+8
    end=end+8
    print(x)
```

But: You're iterating over the string without using the index `i`. If you start at 0, until `len(string)` in *steps of 8*, you could re-write and cleanup the loop like this, and don't need the emptiness check since the loop stops at the right point:

```py
string="01101000011001010110110001101100011011110010000001110111011011110111001001101100011001000010000000100001"
listnew = []
step = 8  # this is good as a step
for start in range(0, len(string), step):
    y = string[start:start + step]  # substring, move this to the top of the loop
    print(y, end=' ')
    listnew.append(y)
    x = chr(int(y ,2))
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get too many characters out of your string because your loop is too large.  When `start` goes beyond the end of the string, the slicing returns an empty string.

Try:

```
for start in range(0,len(string),8):
    end = start+8
```